# She went to sleep. (to inf. vs. preposition to)

Tags: verbs, intransitive

> She went to sleep.

1. to inf. : She went (somewhere) in order to sleep.
2. preposition to : She fell asleep.

Which one is more likely at the first glance of the sentence above if you are a native English speaker?

Comment: The same one here: go to work (to inf. or preposition to?)

Comment: She went there to sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2.

It almost always means that in any context unless otherwise stated (eg 'she went to sleep *at her friend's house*').

Don't compare it to "go to work", because work is more often than not a physical place away from the home that you 'go' to, whereas 'sleep' is a state, not a physical place. Most people would say "*she went to bed*" to mean the act of physically taking yourself somewhere to sleep.

Comment: I remember being made nervous as a small, early-reading child by inscriptions on gravestones that said things like 'Went to sleep July 5th 1899", or 'Asleep in the arms of Jesus'. Not helped by my mother saying that Granny was no longer around because she  'had been tired and went to sleep'.